# Check if a user object is found before destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a Rails 3.2 app and I have just a quick question when doing destroy.
First I make a find to find the user I need to delete but I do not want to make destroy
if it is not found.

This is my code and I feel something is missing on line 3 (if @user):

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])

 if @user
  @user.destroy
 else
  "User not found"
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this with `try`:

```
if User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).try(:destroy)
  "User found and destroyed"
else
  "User not found or was not successfully destroyed"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not work and will raise an exception, you should do:

```
 @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

 if @user
   @user.destroy! #methods with bang raise an exception, I advise you to use them
   #no flash msg?
 else
   flash[:error] = "User not found"
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not found, you'd get an exception

If you don't want it, do :

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
```

Then your test is correct